# Send action from custom View in NSToolbarItem

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar

I created a `Custom View` as a Toolbar Item. Creating an `action` from the Toolbar item now doesn't work (it's not fired). Any ideas?

Comment: If you have no controls in your custom view, why do you not simply set an image for an NSToolbarItem?

Answer (score 0):

The `action` of an `NSToolbarItem` is only used if you leave the default view in place. Setting a custom view will mean that you need to setup any target/action/callbacks with that custom view instead: e.g. if you set a custom button or segmented control, you should set the `target` and `action` on that.

Comment: I found that on the internet, but this has two problems: 1) A `NSView` doesn't have an `action` and 2) this will not solve the problem, that clicking on the label below the custom view doen't fire the action.

Comment: The exact approach will depend on the view being set (as you noted: the base NSView has no built-in target/action). If it's some type of NSControl, you can use target/action. Some custom views might have a block callback. But if you are using some other type of custom view that has no built-in click action functionality, you will have to add that yourself.

Comment: I thought so, but I cannot find any example for this ;) ... but still: If I could do that, the click on the `_NSToolbarItemViewerLabelView` doesn't do anything (I just tried everything with a `NSButton` instead of a view)